# apps-scripts: remote database password security

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script

I connect to a remote sqlserver database using the jdbc service. My apps script has my password and userid. Is there a security risk involved. I ask because javascript is open to inspection; are app-scripts open to users?

What is the best way to get that secure information into an app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even hard coded values don't show up in the javascript when rendered by the browser. That is because all the code that you write runs on the server side (except client handlers). 
However, if you share a script or spreadsheet with the script with another user, the code is visible to the other user.

You can store your username and password in a spreadsheet that only you have access to and read from there during runtime. However, ensure that the script runs under your id (i.e only published as a web app).

Comment: I will give this a try. It sounds like the code of webapps is not visible, and that the webapp can go and grab data from a spreadsheet that only I own, even though the webapp is being used by someone who is not authenticated and therefore does not have access to my spreadsheet. 

I will have to experiment a bit. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [UserProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_userproperties) service.  It's values are only available to you and if you decide to make the application multi-user, you could even direct users to store their unique sql username/password in their own UserProperties.

Comment: Problem there is I want users (of webapp) to have access to my sqlserver account through the interface. So the interface will go grab the data in a controlled manner. So I need to figure out if my webapps  can run with (some of) my user properties, but without it being me...

Comment: You can do that, its all in how you deploy the app